# How can I deal with an "Failed to construct WebSocket: The URL is invalid" JavaScript exception?

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to configure my Vaadin Application (version 7.7.15) to support IPv6 and somehow the URL is encoded incorrectly.

For example: If the ip is: fd71:2d5a:e15a:1ed3::1, on browser you access it like this: http://[fd71:2d5a:e15a:1ed3::1].

The problem is that the character '[' is replaced with '%5B' and the character ']' is replaced with '%5D'.

This encoding cause a "Failed to construct WebSocket: The URL is invalid; JavaScriptException [SyntaxError]" as the picture is describing.

But if I modify the @Push annotation from @Push(transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR) to @Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING), I am able to access the UI, but the API Calls are very very slow.

Can anyone tell me please how can I escape those characters from been encoded?

Thank you,
George

[image: WebSocket Error]

Comment: It looks like that your server or proxy does not support Websockets. Your application may look like it is mostly working, but Push will not work correctly.

Comment: You could try to change your @Push annotation to @Push(transport=Transport.LONG_POLLING) and check if everything works. That will change Push to use HTTP instead of Websockets.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quick. Related to your first response, I have a question: How it is actually working with an IPv4 address? I've configured the app to support both IP addresses IPv4/IPv6. When I access it throw IPv4 it's working fine.

Comment: Looks like it is actually saying SyntaxError in Atmosphere client side, I guess. There seems to be extra characters in the  IPv6 URL:  %5B and %5D (that is '[' and ']' ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updates:**

This bug was resolved into the Atmosphere Framework as you can see in the pull request linked below:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript/pull/243

Regards,
George